# Most efficient method to find maximum element and list of maximum elements from a 2-d array?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a list `arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` here maximum element is `9` and maximum elements from 1 d list is `[3,6,9]`.

Comment: Define efficient. That is, do you want least code, or fewest cpu cycles?

Comment: @Jonathan fewest cpu cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If using numpy

```
>>>import numpy as np

>>>array=np.random.rand(3,3)
>>>print(array)
>>>print(array.max(axis=1))
```

```
>>>[[ 0.76562624  0.45225107  0.74276688]
     [ 0.84390255  0.03384166  0.40036534]
     [ 0.00371805  0.47996941  0.15593055]]

>>>[ 0.76562624  0.84390255  0.47996941]
```

## Alternatively using map and max

```
>>>arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>>print(list(map(max,arr)))
```

```
>>>[3,6,9]
```

## To print maximum element

```
>>>print(max(map(max,arr)))
```

```
>>>9
```

## Using numpy

```
>>>print(array.max())
```

Answer (score 2):

Flatten the array with a nested comprehension for the max of all elements:

```
>>> max(x for row in arr for x in row)
9
```

Use a list comprehension for the max of each row:

```
>>> [max(row) for row in arr]
[3, 6, 9]
```

*Note*: The list comp is slightly faster than using `map(max, arr)`.  Consider using `numpy` if you want better performance than pure Python loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
>>> max_row = map(max, arr)
>>> list(max_row)
[3, 6, 9]
>>> maxmax = max(max_row)
>>> maxmax
9
>>> _
```