# Return the maximun of a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, max

I want to return the max value of a matrix.
For example this is my matrix:

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 6, 0, 1], [0, 1, 4, 0, 0]]
```

I want to return the max so here '10'

This is my code but I have an error:

```
max = 0
for i in range(len(matrix)+1):
   for j in range(len(matrix[0])+1):
      if matrix[i][j] > matrix[i+1][j+1]:
         max =  matrix[i][j]
print(max)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lists of lists are really inefficient for storing matrices. You should consider using numpy instead.

Comment: Related/dupe  [Most efficient method to find maximum element and list of maximum elements from a 2-d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48195041/674039)

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues with your code, I suggest you use the [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function:

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 6, 0, 1], [0, 1, 4, 0, 0]]

result = max(max(row) for row in matrix)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to do it:

1. Fix your method. In Python, lists are zero-based so you need to only iterate from `i = 0` to `len(matrix) - 1`. Doing `for i in range(len(matrix)):` does this for you. You don't need to do `range(len(matrix) + 1))`. Also, you should only replace the current maxval if the element you're looking at is greater than *`maxval`*.

So,

```
maxval = -9999999
for i in range(len(matrix)):
   for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
      if matrix[i][j] > maxval: 
         maxval =  matrix[i][j]
print(maxval)
# Out: 10
```

Or, a more pythonic way is to iterate over the elements instead of accessing them through their indices

```
maxval = -9999999
for row in matrix:
    for element in row:
        if element > maxval:
            maxval = element

# maxval: 10
```

Notice I use `maxval` instead of `max` so as not to shadow python's inbuilt `max()` function.

2. Use numpy (if you're already using it for other things). Like [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) mentioned in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64789722/return-the-maximun-of-a-matrix/64789781#comment114552663_64789722), a `numpy` array is a *much*  better way to store matrices instead of lists of lists. Why? [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)

```
import numpy as np

matrix = [[0, 1, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 6, 0, 1], [0, 1, 4, 0, 0]]

maxval = np.max(matrix)
# maxval: 10
```

3. Iterate over rows, create a list of max values in each row. Then find the max of this list

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 6, 0, 1], [0, 1, 4, 0, 0]]

rowmax = [max(row) for row in matrix]
maxval = max(rowmax)

# or in one line:
maxval = max(max(row) for row in matrix)
```

4. Use `map`. This is essentially the same as the previous method.

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 6, 0, 1], [0, 1, 4, 0, 0]]

maxval = max(map(max, matrix))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 6, 0, 1], [0, 1, 4, 0, 0]]
max1 = 0
for sub_list in  matrix:
    for item in sub_list:
        if item>max1:
            max1=item
```